# How to create a table with only read and write permission for all the user in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to create a table which is public to all the user. So when I create a new user they already have access to read and write it but not delete it. Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `PUBLIC` role. So:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON mytable TO PUBLIC
```

will do what you want

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_privileges.htm#CIHHGIGB